# Find primary/dominant color of an image with canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, node-canvas

I am new to node.js.

I´ve read the thread about Node.js Image Libraries and it seems that [GM](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) seems to be the most

advanced. I am trying to find out the most dominant color of an image using nodejs.

Then I have found this script [color-thief](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief) , which is very interesting. It uses canvas to 
determine the color.

I found this [node-canvas](https://github.com/learnboost/node-canvas), which allows to create server side canvas.

Can I use color-thief and node-canvas together? Or am I missing something? Maybe someone has a better solution for nodejs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, there is a port for `color-thief` in node.js.

Get the node.js friendly port here:

https://npmjs.org/package/thief

Install the package like this:

```
$ npm install thief
```

Include color-thief in your node script like this:

```
var thief=require("thief");
```

And use color-thief normally! ...

Comment: I can't find this code on Github, apparently the link is broken.  It doesn't install for me because of build issues with the node-gyp.  I wonder if there are any other solutions out there that don't require a build.

Comment: Painfully, I was able to get it to build with Visual Studio 2012 following these instructions: http://programanddesign.com/cpp/installing-node-canvas-on-windows/